# Find all exact squares

Tags: calculus

I need all the values for $n$, where $n^2 + 2019$ is exact square.
I've found all up to $999,999,999$.

> Should I keep going or am I not going to find any higher?

Comment: Hint:  $n^2+2019=m^2\implies 2019=(m+n)(m-n)$.

Comment: and $2019=(673)(3)$

Comment: I get 8 solutions. If we assume $n,a>0$ then there are only two solutions.

Comment: How come 8 solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking for the solutions for $a$ in the equation: $a^2 = n^2 + 2019$ where $a, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Rewriting,

\begin{align*}
a^2 - n^2 = 2019 \\
(a + n)(a - n) =2019
\end{align*}

Does this provide enough of a hint to continue?

Comment: Yep, absolutely!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $n^2+2019=a^2$ for some $a$, then $a$ needs to be at least $n+1$. If $n$ is big enough, then $(n+1)^2>n^2+2019$ so there can be no more solutions after that. Can you compute whether checking until $999,999,999$ is enough?

Comment: Yep, found out I should have stopped much before that :D